# Orienting Controls on Ribbon.xaml

Tags: xaml, ribbon, visio, ribbon-control

I have a Visio Addin that I have been adding controls to. I have a simple problem but I'm struggling to find an answer to.

I have these four controls in a group. I just added a new one called `Query Preference`.

I would like to align this in such a way where `Modern Shapes` shows up under `Query Preference` in the highlighted area below.

[image: Ribbon Image]

The Xaml code for this group is as follows.

I'm fairly certain there is alignment property, but I can't find for the group tag to do what I want.

Does anyone have experience with this?

```
<group id="connectionGroup" label="Manage">
  <button id="authenticate" label="Configure Connection" size="normal" getImage="GetImage" onAction="OnAction" getEnabled="GetEnabled" supertip="Set the server and authentication information"/>
  <button id="stencil" label="Generate Stencil" size="normal" getImage="GetImage" onAction="OnAction" getEnabled="GetEnabled" supertip="Generate a new stencil using the metamodel of the current server"/>
  <menu id="modernClassicShapesDropdown" getLabel="GetShapeStyleLabel" getImage="GetShapeStyleImage" getEnabled="GetEnabled" supertip="Determine how new shapes will be rendered">
    <button id="modernShapes" label="Modern Shapes" getImage="GetImage" onAction="OnShapeStyleAction"/>
    <button id="classicShapes" label="Classic Shapes"  getImage="GetImage" onAction="OnShapeStyleAction"/>
  </menu>
  <menu id="queryPreference" label="Query Preference" getImage="GetImage" getEnabled="GetEnabled" supertip="Determines how much Shape data is queried.">
    <button id="Low" label="Low" onAction="OnQueryPreferenceAction" supertip="Only component name and description are queried and available in shape data. Select this option for fastest drawing time."/>
    <button id="Medium" label="Medium" onAction="OnQueryPreferenceAction" supertip="Only native component properties are queried. Calculated properties are not initially available in shape data."/>
    <button id="High" label="High" onAction="OnQueryPreferenceAction" supertip="All component properties are queried and available in shape data, including calculated properties."/>
  </menu>
</group>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just move the "Modern Shapes" menu item to after "Query Preference" and then insert a blank line:

```
<button id="junk42" label=" " />
```

Comment: This is a more effective solution than you would think. I was hoping for a layout option but that may be wishful thinking as the  attributes available to the ribbon are more limited. But Ill take this. Thanks.